# Can someone break down how localization file ( .mo, .po ) generation works?

Tags: zend-framework, internationalization, gettext, mo

I'm trying to grok `gettext`.

Here's how I ***think*** it works -

First you use some sort of po editor and tell it to scan a directory for your application, create these ".po" files, the application makes a po file for each file scanned which contains a string in a programming language, then compile them to binary mo files, to which `gettext` parses, and you call a method using a high level API such as `Zend_Translate` and specify you want to use `gettext`, it can be setup to cache translations and it just returns those.

The part I'm really unclear about is how the editing of po files is done really, it's manual - right? Then when the compilation is done of course the application relies on the binary mo files.

And if someone could provide useful linux applications for editing `.po` files I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial on [NLS using GNU gettext](https://web.archive.org/web/20130802092826/http://oriya.sarovar.org/docs/gettext/) should help you understand the process.

As for editing .po files, there's at least two applications (apart from vi :-): [gtranslator](http://gtranslator.sourceforge.net/) and [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/).

Comment: Do you use any vim specific plugins, or are none really needed?

Comment: I've never used a plugin for vim, but there's something at http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=695

Comment: I took a read and I might have missed some information, but: 1. Say we're dealing with a python/php web app, what's a typical local to store the po/mo files? Is there a standard directory I can use? 2. Do you use `xgettext` to extract the strings from source code? I think I got most of that information, but if someone could provide a lengthy dumbed-down and less technical explanation and throw in practical real-world tips that'd be great.

Comment: Usually you set LOCALEDIR to $PREFIX/share/locale (prefix could be /usr, /usr/local, ...) then for ecah language the files will be in, say, fr/LC_MESSAGES/yourappname.mo. When extracting strings, I go with xgettext. Didn't bother looking for something else when xgettext does what I need.

Comment: Ok one last thing - say you have around ~100 or so files and 50 of them have strings that need to be i18n'd. It doesn't concatenate them all into one .mo file, does it? I was curious since you typed `yourappname.mo`.

Comment: All the strings will be in the same .mo and there will be one different .mo per language (ie, en/yourappname.mo, es/yourappname.mo, fr/yourappname.mo and so on).